# Swagger Gateway MicroService Aggregation

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger, microservices

I am developing a microservice application using SpringBoot. There is Gateway Microservice which is public facing, it redirects requests to particular microservice (which are running on different hosts).

Now, I've multiple microservices, each microservice has exposed their APIs using Swagger. We would like to aggregate all these API Swagger docs for public clients.

Temporary solution we've incorporated is, just copied the Swagger Annotated classes for each microservice in Gateway Service. What is ***the right way*** to do it?

Comment: Did you look at Netflix Zuul ?

Comment: I have not, let me give it a try and come back :). Thanks for your input @StefaanNeyts

Comment: Thanks, @StefaanNeyts.  I tried it and it worked like a charm. I've posted the code as an answer so it will be helpful to other users.

Comment: Nicely done. Thx for sharing your solution. Up!

Comment: @StefaanNeyts All of the request should have valid authorization header in the format `Authorizatoin: bearer: <token>`. This token will get validated on Gateway and if correct request will be passed on to particular service without auth header. How can I add this token to every request via Swagger?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I used Zuul and that solved my problem 
This is how my app would be deployed 
[image: app deployment]

I added this in my `pom.xml`

```
<dependencies>
        ....
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

My main class looks like this

```
 @EnableZuulProxy
 @SpringBootApplication
 @EnableSwagger2
 public class Application {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
         SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
     }

    @Bean
    UiConfiguration uiConfig() {
        return new UiConfiguration("validatorUrl", "list", "alpha", "schema",
            UiConfiguration.Constants.DEFAULT_SUBMIT_METHODS, false, true, 60000L);
    }
 }
```

I created the aggregator for swagger document

```
@Component
@Primary
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class SwaggerAggregatorController implements SwaggerResourcesProvider {
    @Override
    public List<SwaggerResource> get() {
        List<SwaggerResource> resources= new ArrayList<>();
        SwaggerResource swaggerResource = new SwaggerResource();
        swaggerResource.setName("cust-service");
        swaggerResource.setLocation("/cust/v2/api-docs");
        swaggerResource.setSwaggerVersion("2.0");

        resources.add(swaggerResource);
        return resources;
    }
}
```

I can add more microservices in this field. (Can be improved to be read from config file)

My `application.properties` looks like following

```
...
server.port=8001

zuul.routes.cust.path=/cust/**
zuul.routes.cust.url=http://1.1.1.2:8002/cust-service/
...
```

Comment: is this possible using spring cloud gateway ?

Comment: `return new UiConfiguration method ` is marked as deprecated in 2.9.2 of Springfox

Comment: @Mr_LinDowsMac You can use whatever the latest and I think it would work the same way. The problem I was trying to address was to aggregate all the swagger docs