# Swagger Aggregation: Add authorization header to all

Tags: java, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0, netflix-zuul

As shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49292843/swagger-gateway-microservice-aggregation), I've created a swagger aggregator. Code snippet looks like following

```
@Component
@Primary
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class SwaggerAggregatorController implements SwaggerResourcesProvider {
    @Override
    public List<SwaggerResource> get() {
        List<SwaggerResource> resources= new ArrayList<>();

        SwaggerResource custSwagger = new SwaggerResource();
        custSwagger.setName("cust-service");
        custSwagger.setLocation("/cust/cust-service/v2/api-docs");
        custSwagger.setSwaggerVersion("2.0");
        resources.add(cstSwagger);

        return resources;
    }
}
```

Now, I want each request to have an Authorization header. Which will get validated at Gateway service and if it's valid, the request will get passed on to particular service without authorization header.