# API gateway microservices and swagger collection

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, swagger, microservices

I have an API gateway (AWS) in front of multiple microservices (.NET) . The microservices each expose swagger documentation independently. How can I aggregate all those swagger endpoints from multiple APIs into the API gateway to expose to clients as a single documentation page?

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49292843/swagger-gateway-microservice-aggregation) shows an example of this done with Java/SpringBoot but I'm not sure how it could be done with .NET. Are there any examples out there?